# Best way to have a formatted output with Perl

Tags: perl, formatting

I want to output strings into eight columns, but I want to keep the spacing the same. I don't want to do it in HTML, but I am not sure how to do it normally. Example:

```
Something    Something     Something     Something     Something
Else         Else          Else          Else          Else
Another      Another       Another       Another       Another
```

The amount of rows will change daily, but the column number will always stay the same. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`printf`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#printf)

```
    printf "%-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s %-11s\n",
            $column1, $column2, ..., $column8;
```

Change "11" in the template to whatever value you need.

Comment: That is perfect thanks, when I googled it I found all these complicated methods.

Comment: As eluded, when things seem to get complicated, it generally means you have more control/options.  `printf` is very powerful, but consider `format` if you are going to be printing formatted reports.  `format` gives the ability to add headers/footers, which makes outputting to files easier to modify.

Comment: I dont need to get technical with headers or anything. It is just to have things output in a nice view on a sheet

Comment: Then `printf` is most likely what is needed.  If your data is in an array, see my answer on how to pass the array values as parameters - just pass the whole array list, rather than specifying each node independently.

Answer (score 12):

You could use Perl's [`format`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html).
This is probably the "complicated" method that you don't understand, most likely because it gives you many options (left|center|right justification/padding, leading 0's, etc).

[Perldoc Example](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html#Text-Fields):

```
Example:
   format STDOUT =
   @<<<<<<   @||||||   @>>>>>>
   "left",   "middle", "right"
   .
Output:
   left      middle    right
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_format.htm)'s another tutorial.

#### Working Example: ([Codepad](http://codepad.org/CCjTZXj3))

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    

use strict; 

   sub main{    
      my @arr = (['something1','something2','something3','something4','something5','something6','something7','something8']
                ,['else1'     ,'else2'     ,'else3'     ,'else4'     ,'else5'     ,'else6'     ,'else7'     ,'else8'     ]
                ,['another1'  ,'another2'  ,'another3'  ,'another4'  ,'another5'  ,'another6'  ,'another7'  ,'another8'  ]
                );
      
      for my $row (@arr) {
         format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<  
         @$row
.
         write;
      }

   }    
       
   main();
```

Answer (score 4):

I would look at formatting, but I would do it using [Perl 6's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raku_(programming_language)) (now Raku) Form.pm, which you can obtain as [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edconway/Perl6-Form-0.04/Form.pm) for Perl 5.

The reason for this is that the format builtin has a number of drawbacks, such as having the format statically defined at compile time (i.e., building it dynamically can be painful and usually requires string eval), along with a whole list of other shortcomings, such as lack of useful field types (and you can't extend these in Perl 5).

Comment: `The amount of rows will change daily but the column number will always stay the same.` No need to build dynamically or use eval.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a live example of [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aForm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Perl6::Form;

my @arr = (
    [1..8],
    [9..16],
    [17..24],
);

foreach my $line (@arr) {
    print form
        "{<<<<<} "x8,
        @{$line};
}
```

It will output:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16
17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24
```