# How to write wrapped table format in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm writing in Perl to direct my report in table format but I'm having issue whenever the data filling is texted too long. Is there a way a write the code so that it can wrapped the lines to m ultiple.  Here is my code and output.  Thanks!

```
printf "\n%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "====", "====", "=====" ;
printf "%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "Code", "Item", "Group" ;
printf "%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "====", "====", "=====" ;

foreach my $f (@{$rpt_ptr}) {
printf "%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "$$f{code}", "$$f{item}", "$$f{group}", 
}
```

The output table will be extended to too long if I have the Item list which is too long, ie:-

```
====  =====                                                                                =====      

Code  Item                                                                                 Group

====  =====                                                                                =====

A1011 aaaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc, ddddd, eeeee, fffff, ggggg, hhhhh, iiiii, jjjjjj, kkkkk, llll    B
    B101  cccccc                                                                                 A
```

I'm aspected if I can comes out with a table such like:

```
====  =====                                                                                =====      
Code  Item                                                                                 Group
====  =====                                                                                =====
A1011 aaaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc, ddddd,                                                           B
      eeeee, fffff, ggggg, hhhhh,   
      iiiii, jjjjjj, kkkkk, llll
B101  cccccc                                                                                 A
```

How am I going to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl was originally written to format text files. It includes a rather interesting form generating facility, including the ability to wrap lines the way you've specified. I have not seen it used in a long, long while, but it's still part of the language.

It's in the Perldoc under [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html).

---

#### Example

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my ($invoice, $description, $amount);
while ( chomp ( my $line = <DATA> ) ) {
    ( $invoice, $description, $amount ) = split /:/ => $line;
    write;
}

format STDOUT_TOP =
Invoice   Description       Amount
=======   ===========       =======
.
format STDOUT = 
@<<<<<<   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   @###.##
$invoice, $description,     $amount
          ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          $description
          ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          $description
          ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          $description
          ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          $description
.
__DATA__
One:This line contans a lot of text that I have to process and I have no idea what it is:2.30
Two:Here's another line that contains lots of data that won't fit on a single line:4.40
Three:And one more line of extra long data that may or may not fit on a single line:5.10
```

#### Output

```
Invoice   Description       Amount
=======   ===========       =======
One       This line            2.30
          contans a lot
          of text that I
          have to process
          and I have no
Two       Here's another       4.40
          line that
          contains lots
          of data that
          won't fit on a
Three     And one more         5.10
          line of extra
          long data that
          may or may not
          fit on a single
```

Comment: W, thanks and I have looked into the link you gave, but some how I still not able to get it done.  An example code will be more helpful for me.

Comment: I think it's also part of Perl Programming books, despite hardly ever being used.

Comment: @Grace I've added an example to my answer. The only issue I ran into was that I had to declare my local variables outside the loop in order for my format statement to see the variable. It didn't take too long to figure out.

Comment: @vol7ron and all, thank you for your helps and sample codings. I finally get my prblm solved, and shared my coding as below. I've ticked on David who gives nearest solutions. Big thanks to you all again!

Comment: @DavidW. your format works great, however with this format, the number of lines that `$description` would take to display is fixed (5 lines), so if my string is longer than that it would be truncated and if shorter than 5 lines there will always be empty lines being displayed. Is there any way for the content to be fully displayed if it's too long and without trailing empty lines even if it's short? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @annena, just needed the info you were asking for, too, and found out that you can prefix a format line with ~~ (double tilde) which will then repeat the line, but only if it is not empty ("repeat line until all fields are exhausted").  Sot it is theb ~~@<<<<< @<<<<< ... . See also list of characters in the linked perldoc perlform. Maybe you still need the information 2.5 years later ;)

Answer (score 1):

`format`s are really the way to go.

Here's a solution using [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6%3a%3aForm):

```
use Perl6::Form;

my @data = (
    ['A1011', 'aaaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc, ddddd, eeeee, fffff, ggggg, hhhhh, iiiii, jjjjjj, kkkkk, llll', 'B'],
    ['B101', 'cccccc', ''],
);

print form
    "====  =====                                              =====",
    "Code  Item                                               Group",
    "====  =====                                              =====";

foreach (@data) {
    print form
        "{<<<<}{[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}             {<<}", @$_ ;
}
```

Comment: This is also in the core Perl 5 library too. What's the difference between the `Perl6::Form` and the standard one? They look pretty similar. Granted I haven't played with forms for _mumble mumble_ years. Just curious of the differences.

Comment: @stevenl, thanks but my system do not support Perl6, we're using v5.8.5 built for x86_64-linux and it doesn't support the form.pm either. Any solution for this if I'm not allow to copy over the module? Actually, the input data filling is not fixed. I'll have dereferencing value for that column. I have added foreach loop (for table data filling) for my original coding.

Comment: @Grace 5.8 is ancient.  You should really be at least 5.12 (5.10 at very minimum)

Comment: No choice unless the admin update that but no decision for updating that as I know.

Comment: @Grace [Perl6::Form](http://p3rl.org/Perl6::Form) is a Perl 5 module that should work fine with v5.8.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp for this wrapping the text.
Since your are printing in the file line by line, 
you can take every line in a scalar variable and check the length of that scalar variable and insert new line character `\n`.

like:

```
    $var = "\n%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "====", "====", "=====" ;
    $var .= "%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "Code", "Item", "Group" ;
    $var .= "%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "====", "====", "=====" ;

    ## Adding new line character after 20 characters.
    my $startIndex = 0;

    while( ($startIndex < length($var) && (length($var) > 20) ) {
     print substr($var, $startIndex, 20)  . "\n";
     $startIndex = $startIndex + 20;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your codes, I tried it but it doesn't works for me.  I have modified my original code for table input, which will be the data after the header above.  I'm still  not able toget it done :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want something very basic/specific (not robust), force a line break every fourth comma:

In your loop before the `printf`:

```
$$f{item} =~ s/(,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,)/$1\n/g;
```

---

Best option is probably to use [perlform (5.8.8 for you)](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlform.html) as David suggested

Comment: could you write me a sample?  I need the input field to be able to read from dereferencing value, despite need to split it to multiple line.  Breaking the line whenever seeing the "," isn't practical for my case.  Thanks.

Comment: @Grace: read the top of form section.  I'm not going to write an example when someone else already has.  You have to actually read the documentation

Comment: Here's an example from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3329743/183181

Comment: You might miss it, so here's a link to a better [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_format.htm) from the answer.

Comment: thanks for the link and ref tutorial, but I somehow still not able to get it done. It printout somekind of indently wrong format and shifted output :(.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it done by following code, posted here to share:-

```
foreach my $f (@{$rpt_ptr}) {
#   printf "%-${max1}s %-${max2}s %-15s\n", "$$f{code}", "$$f{item}", "$$f{group}", 
format STDOUT_TOP =
===============     =========================     ========= 
Code                 Item                     Group
===============     =========================     ========= 
.

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<     ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<     @<<<<<<<<
$$f{code}               $$f{item}                                              $$f{group} 
~~                ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                   $$f{item}
.
write ;
}
```

To all who have responded to my question, big thanks for your helps, I greatly appreciate it!