# perl format : how to avoid truncation when i try to print out strings of unfixed length

Tags: perl, format

I'm trying to do debug port and muxing verification in the ASIC,
the signal hierarchy name can be fairly long, for example

```
top.eagleTop.ahb_top.btu.u_ble_core.u_ble_txrx_ctlr.rx_dmem_be_3
```

Right now I'm using pad character for left justification to print out the string

```
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

but it makes my code looks messy. Is there any better way to print a variable length string other than this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3328043/223226

Comment: Please don't use `format`. It isn't very good and no one uses it so you won't get very much help. A `printf` is probably better, but please describe what it is that you want to do.

Comment: I've heard good things about Perl6::Form (Perl6-style forms for Perl5)

Comment: I'm trying to use format to generate the system verilog files, I guess it's much better than the printf

Comment: Ahh, `format`, the very height of Perl 4 fashion....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl's `format` construct isn't used very much any more so you are unlikely to get good advice, but have you read [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) for `format`?

It looks to me like you want the `^*` placeholder, [documented here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html#The-Field-%5E%2A-for-Variable-Width-One-line-at-a-time-Text). It says it is *"for Variable-Width One-line-at-a-time Text"*.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be using `@*` unless your string contains newlines, which it shouldn't. use `^*` instead. And please get into the habit of voting up any questions or answers that help you. Questions and answers on Stack Overflow are there to serve everyone, and an upvote (or downvote) helps other people find the most relevant questions and the better answers.

Comment: @Borodin Good to educate new users about voting, but be aware that you don't gain the [up-voting privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) until you have 15 reputation.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, as I wrote it I was aware that it looked like I was canvassing. I gave up the hunt for votes a long time ago, and I like to do the community thing when I think about it. I wasn't sure where voting kicked in but thanks. (I'm also not sure that rep 1 should even allow questions to be asked!)

Comment: It's clear from your wording that you're trying to educate a new user on how the site works, not begging for upvotes.